# Crazyflie USB 3.0 incompability

Tags: python, libusb, crazyflie

I've been tinkering with [Crazyflie](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/crazyflie-nano-quadcopter-kit-10dof-with-crazyradio-bccfk02a-p-1365.html) lately, but it seems the firmware doesn't detect USB 3.0 properly. There's a way around it, but when I tried to follow the instruction, even the dongle is not detected.

```
> cd crazyradio-firmware
> python usbtools/launchBootloader.py
Error!, cannot find the CrazyRadio USB dongle!
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a blogpost, *[Crazyradio firmware with USB3.0 fix](http://crazyflie.blogspot.com/2013/05/crazyradio-firmware-with-usb30-fix.html)*, about a firmware fix for USB 3.0 support.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update the Crazyradio firmware to work with USB3.0 - and of course, if you're on a USB3.0 machine, you won't be able to enumerate the Crazyradio in the first place to fix it!  You have a few options:

- Update the Crazyradio firmware with the USB3.0 fix from a USB2.0 machine
- Use a USB2.0 hub, between the Crazyradio and your USB3.0 host machine
- Update the Crazyradio firmware [via SPI](http://wiki.bitcraze.se/projects%3acrazyradio%3aspi_programming)

[Here's how I did it](http://crazyflie.blogspot.com/2013/05/crazyradio-firmware-with-usb30-fix.html) from a USB2.0 machine.

Comment: thank you the reply! I did see your blog before i post this, basically I'm at the point where I'm trying to [flash out the firmware](http://wiki.bitcraze.se/projects:crazyradio:programming).

Comment: ..but it got stuck at that process.

I searched the forum a bit too, and although people are having trouble with USB 3.0 they've never had encountered with the same issue i'm having right now.

but i havent tried your other 2 options, will try that hopefully it work otherwise $$$ gone to waste.

Comment: If you haven't already, be sure to post your questions on the Bitcraze Forums (http://forum.bitcraze.se/) - the community and guys who created the device are very active on there.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else failed for me, until I followed the instructions here:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-VirtualBox-USB-Support-111715.shtml

...and they worked!
The VMWare Linux environment now talks to the Crazyradio PA.

What is the issue here? Can't the VMWare image be shipped with the bitcraze user in the correct group?